# How do I map my Program Files directory to another disk?

Tags: windows-7, mklink

I am trying to map my Program Files (x86) directory on my boot SSD to my secondary drive to save space.

I am using this exact command:

```
MKLINK /j \\Server-7\C:\"Program Files (x86)" \\Server-7\D:\"Program Files (x86)"
```

This command is run with admin privileges from the admin account and ONLY /J switch works for this. I can't get past this error message:

```
Local volumes are required to complete the operation
```

I know Windows has to quit using the main (C:) drive to make these changes, but it is not giving me an option to restart to allow these changes to be applied, and I am not sure how to get this to work from here.

The locations are all correct, and the syntax is correct, and the switch is correct, and it knows it needs to use the main (C:) drive, but I can't get any further. I am running out of space EXTREMELY FAST because it is only a 64GB SSD.

How can I map my Program Files directory to another disk?

Comment: Why can't you just use `C:\"Program Files (x86)"`? (as opposed to `\\Server-7\C:\"Program Files (x86)"`)